# System does not boot after kernel update

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, kali-linux, bluetooth, software-updates

I have Kali Linux 2020.2 install on my laptop. Today I updated kernel and tried rebooting system, but now it's not booting up, not even in older versions on kernel. It's showing some error but I couldn't understand it. I am attaching the error snap. Please tell me what's wrong with it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a corrupted filesystem, it is asking for the root password so you can run `fsck`.

Comment: @icarus what can I do with fsck?

Comment: `fsck` is the file system checker. my **guess** is that after the new kernel was installed the system was rebooted incorrectly and that left the filesystem corrupted. If you don't know any better then just type `ctrl-d` and hope.

Comment: ctrl-d didn't do anything useful. I logged in as root and used fsck on os partition. But it didn't work because partition was mounted. I tried to unmount partition but it showed target is busy. So how am I supposed to run fsck on that partition?

Comment: The root partition cannot be unmounted, but it can be mounted in read-only mode for a filesystem check. If the filesystem check makes any modifications to the root filesystem, you should reboot after the check is complete and not attempt to bring the system up without rebooting. If the problem is with a non-root filesystem, it will be unmounted and ready for checking when you enter the rescue shell. To find the filesystem with the problem, compare `/etc/fstab` to `/proc/mounts` or run `mount -a` in the rescue shell and read the error message.